# DDR3 SDRAM compatibility: clock speed and timings

Tags: memory, ddr3, memory-timings, sdram, memory-speed

I want to upgrade my computer’s DDR3 SDRAM, replacing the single module that it currently has with newer ones. I am wondering if I must (or ought to) stick fairly strictly to the DDR3-1333 version specified by the computer’s manufacturer, or if I can just use any (or some) higher-speed (but otherwise compatible) module.

After reading a bit on the topic and concluding that I am thoroughly baffled by it all, here are a few questions (I hope that they are coherent):

1. Speaking of default values (before any possible user tweak), are the actual clock speed and timings of memory *automatically* and *optimally* set by the controller (somehow reading capabilities off the modules), or does it use a fixed configuration (hardcoded in the firmware) that must be matched when installing modules?
2. Given a motherboard that calls for a certain SDRAM clock speed, what will happen if I use an otherwise compatible module of any higher standard speed (i.e., up to DDR3-2133/PC3-17000)?
   Possible reasons (probably, most or all of them incorrect) why this might not work include, for example:

   2.1. *It will not work if the controller does not support the module’s
   higher speed. After all, there is no guarantee that a DDR3 SDRAM
   controller will support all speeds in the JESD79 standard.*

   2.2. *It will not work if the system does not let me manually adjust the
   clock speed and/or timings, because it won’t do it automatically.*

   2.3. *It will not work if the controller does not support timings that
   closely match the module’s latency (adjusted for the reduced clock
   speed): the data won’t remain available long enough on the module’s
   output pins.*

   2.4. *It will not work if the module does not support the controller’s maximal speed. After all, there is no guarantee that a DDR3 SDRAM module will support all lower speeds in the JESD79 standard.*

   2.5. *It will not work if the module does not support timings that are compatible with the controller’s maximal speed (i.e., adjusted for the reduced speed).*

   2.6. Etc.
3. If it could work, then beside a possible higher price for the modules, what would be the downsides or pitfalls of such a configuration?
   A possible reason could be:

   3.1. *The controller will not adjust the timings taking into account the reduced clock speed; instead, it will just use the timings advertised by the memory module for its maximal clock speed, resulting in lower performance (than could be obtained with a lower speed but lower CL module).
      For example, when using a 11-11-11 DDR3-2133 at 1333 speed, the controller will use 11-11-11 instead of 7-7-7.*

   3.2. Etc.

In short, I would really like to understand the reasons why this would/could or wouldn’t/couldn’t work. Yet I’m pretty sure that I couldn’t stomach reading the standard itself.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the motherboard make/model?

Comment: @Ash I’m upgrading a Lenovo T420, with an Intel Core i5-2540M, which Intel says supports DDR3 1066/1333, with a maximal bandwidth of 21.3 GB/s. That being said, I am not so much looking for a _“yes/no”_ answer specific to that machine but rather for some general understanding of the problem (constraints and possibilities), so that I can deal with other machines in the future. Hopefully, this can also help others. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, it's a laptop. With desktop motherboards DDR3 incompatibility is relatively rare, and in general will downclock to something they can run, but I don't have enough xp with laptop boards to answer. Following the manufacturer specs -- as you're already doing -- is your safest option.

Answer (score -1):

It will probably work but you still won't get more than 1333 because that's what your mobo supports.